# AWS Network Security on lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS lambda function that calls the GitHub API and functions OK. This was using the default network settings for the lambda (i.e. No VPC)

I have added new code to access an AWS MySQL DB.

Initially, the db code did not work as it could not access the database. To get this to work I added A VPC as per the image and now the MySQL access is OK. However, GitHub API access has stopped working.

[image]

As far as I can see the VPC is set up to allow outbound internet access so not quite sure what the issue is.

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

When you add your lambda to a VPC, it loses internet access by default. You will need to give your VPC access to the internet, you will need to create:

- A new subnet with a public IP
- A Internet gateway attached to the VPC
- A NAT Gateway to bridge the private subnets to the new subnet

All the steps can be found on [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)